# What happened to pasted SmartObjects from Illustrator to Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, smartobject

In older versions of Photoshop (before photoshop cc 2015, latest update)the app used to create smart objects from pasted paths out of Illustrator. When I wanted to edit the Paths (double clicking on the smart object in PS) Illustrator was opened and I was able to simply adjust the paths. After saving the PS Smart Object got updated. Pretty simple, pretty cool.

Now when I paste paths form Illustrator into photoshop, the app makes some kind of cloud smart object, with a little cloud icon before the layer. If I want to edit my pasted artwork, by double clicking, I get an error something like:

> This element can't be edited in Photoshop..

*(I actually get the german error)*

I can't believe its not possible to paste illustrator artwork in Photoshop anymore as well as not having the opportunity to change the artwork afterwards.

Comment: Open  illustrator in your OS, Then Double click the Smart-object thumbnail In PS. I have cc2014 so can't exactly check what the problem is but try this May be this Can help.

Comment: @Rishab this is exactly whats not working anymore

Answer (score 4):

I have the latest CC update on both programs, and I tested your issue, and I believe the problem lies in the "Add to my current library" option when pasting:

[image: Pasting from AI to PS]

When that box is checked, it behaves exactly as you described. But if you uncheck the box, it uses the old behavior that you're used to.